# How to redisplay dired buffer after changing listing-switches

Tags: dired

This sample code doesn't work:

```el
(defun toggle-hidden-in-dired ()
  (interactive)
  (setq dired-listing-switches 
        (if (equal dired-listing-switches "-l --group-directories-first")
            "-la --group-directories-first"
          "-l --group-directories-first"))
  (revert-buffer))
```

Comment: You probably have set up different flags for `ls` in `dired`, and this code makes assumptions about them. I can post more reliable code from my init ifle later.

Comment: I wrote this generic higher-order function that will return functions that toggle `dired` flags: https://github.com/DoMiNeLa10/.emacs.d/blob/master/config/my-defuns-lexical.el#L30-L40. You need to put it in a file that has `lexical-scoping` set to t, and then you can bind it to a key like this: https://github.com/DoMiNeLa10/.emacs.d/blob/master/config/my-customization.el#L153.

Answer (score 1):

Try this instead:

```el
(defun toggle-hidden-in-dired ()
  (interactive)
  (setq dired-actual-switches  (if (equal dired-actual-switches
                                          "-l --group-directories-first")
                                   "-la --group-directories-first"
                                 "-l --group-directories-first"))
  (dired-readin))
```